# Swift Run the block of Timer without timer in first time

Tags: swift, xcode

I created a timer and set it to repeat every 30 seconds
the timer waits 30 seconds to run the first time, then another 30 seconds for the second time, I wanted it to run the first time without the 30 seconds, is there any way?

```
Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 30, repeats: true) { timer in
    if iteration >= 0 {
        runCommands()
        iteration -= 1
        if iteration == 0 { exit(0) }
    }
}
```

Comment: Put your code in a funktion. Call it after setting up the timer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just call `fire`. It does what the name implies.

```
Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 30, repeats: true) { timer in
    if iteration >= 0 {
        runCommands()
        iteration -= 1
        if iteration == 0 {exit(0)}
    }
}.fire()
```

Comment: Good point. Much simpler than my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have no reference to your timer. Make one!

```
let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer...
```

Now in the next line you can say `timer.fire()`. This causes the timer to execute its block immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Either refactor the code that's called from the timer closure to be a function, or put the closure into a variable. Then invoke the function/closure explicitly:

```
typealias TimerClosure = (_: Timer?) -> Void

let timerClosure: TimerClosure = { [weak self] timer in
    guard let self = self else { return }
    if self.iteration >= 0 {
        self.runCommands()
        self.iteration -= 1
        if self.iteration == 0 {exit(0)}
    }
}
Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 30, repeats: true, block: timerClosure )
timerClosure(nil)
```

}

### Edit:

The approach above will work, but as others pointed out, you can also call `fire()` on your timer manually.

I'll leave the above part of the answer since it shows how to set up a local variable containing a closure and then both pass it to a function and call it directly, but that's not really needed here. Instead, just do this:

```
let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 30, repeats: true) { [weak self] timer in
    guard let self = self else { return }
    if self.iteration >= 0 {
        self.runCommands()
        self.iteration -= 1
        if self.iteration == 0 { exit(0) }
    }
}
timer.fire()
```

Comment: Completely unnecessary.

Comment: That's right, I forgot about `fire()`.